# Window gap, filler piece or not?

Tags: basement, gap, sealant

I recently installed new windows in my basement (concrete walls). After checking for level and plumb, I’m left with a 3/4“ gap under the new window (exterior side). The window mounts flush with the concrete everywhere else, but the bottom edge of the concrete is tapered (assuming to prevent water buildup).

I’m not sure if I should just use sealant in that big of a space or shove a filler piece in there. Hoping someone can help with a suggestion on which would be better and if it ends up being the latter, what material should I use for the filler piece.

Comment: Some pics sure would help you out here.

Comment: You're not wrong. Omitted despite my better judgement. Will do so when I get home.